# Lightning out : Access-Control-Allow-Origin error // CORS added

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-out, cors

We want to add a Lightning component to an external page. OAuth token is working, and the page's URL is added to the CORS list. However, we are still getting an error:

> "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://xxxxxx' is therefore
>   not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500."

However, there is a funny thing. When having a look on the browser's console on the network calls, there are 2 calls to the app's url:

https://xxxxxx/c/PSA_lout.app?aura.format=JSON&aura.formatAdapter=LIGHTNING_OUT

The first one is an OPTION HTTP method and gets a 200 status code as well as a correct **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header (which is set in the org's CORS settings).
However, the second call (which is a GET call, so the actual download of the script) gets a 500 error code, because there is no **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** header.

Looks for me that our org's settings are fine -- maybe something is wrong on the page's javascript side?

This is the javascript piece on the page:

> ```
>   function insertComponent(access_token, instance_url) {
>       console.log('start to load');           
>       $Lightning.use(
>           'c:PSA_lout',
>           function() {
>               $Lightning.createComponent(
>                   'c:PSA_Timetracker',
>                   {},
>                   'lDiv',
>                   function(cmp) {
>                       console.log('it is started.');
>                   }
>               );
>           },
>           instance_url,
>           access_token);      
>         }
> ```

Comment: Hi, did you resolve it ? I am facing the same issue!